# Can one combine HTML and Apex in one line in a URL?

Tags: urlhacking, custom-url

The following HTML works fine. It sends the user to a specific URL. What I want is to default a custom field to the current user like this `&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv={!User.Name}&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv_lkid=
{!User.Id}`

So I need to append it to the URL but somehow have SF get the User Name and ID and populate the URL with it so it pre-populates the field and not to just add it as text. Can this be done and if so, how?

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Grant_Proposal__c" showHeader="false" >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://eu3.salesforce.com/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9&nooverride=1"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is called `URL hacking`. You can search stack exchange for that keyword and will find tons of the related information: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=url+hacking+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Not what I am asking my friend. I need to how (if possible) to do the following and get SF to populate the user.id and user.name. <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://eu3.salesforce.com/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9&nooverride&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv={!User.Name}&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv_lkid=
{!User.Id}=1"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Visualforce [Merge field $User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm) to substitute current user fields inside both html & visualforce markup.

also you don't have to hardcode your instance url - just use the relative url like below so that it works across environments

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Grant_Proposal__c" showHeader="false" >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv={!$User.FirstName}&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv_lkid={!$User.Id}&nooverride=1"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

and if you can use a custom controller, you can generate the entire url is apex so that you don't need to hardcode record type id & the field ids.